# Check if the client accepts cookie in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

Is there any way to check if the client accepts cookies only with javascript code?

Comment: Sure, try setting one and reading it.

Answer (score 24):

This should do the trick:

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
  document.cookie = "__verify=1";
  var supportsCookies = document.cookie.length >= 1 && 
                        document.cookie.indexOf("__verify=1") !== -1;
  var thePast = new Date(1976, 8, 16);
  document.cookie = "__verify=1;expires=" + thePast.toUTCString();
  return supportsCookies;
}
```

This sets a cookie with session-based expiration, checks for it's existence, and then sets it again in the past, removing it.

Comment: Why `document.cookie.length > 1` and not `document.cookie.length >= 1`?

Comment: it is not working for ie. For chrome and firefox it returns false when cookies are disabled , but in the case of the ie it returns true although the cookies are disabled , Please note that i am using the IE11. Please help !!!!

Answer (score 7):

The [`cookieEnabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/cookieEnabled) property returns a Boolean value that specifies whether or not cookies are enabled in the browser

```
<script>
if (navigator.cookieEnabled) {
    // Cookies are enabled
}
else {
    // Cookies are disabled
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Stephen It does seem to work at least from IE7 when emulating in IE10. Do you have any source?

Comment: Emulating an older IE version from a newer one, is not very trustworthy in  my experience. And that's putting it mildly. Also, browsers do have a history of lying about their capabilities when "asked". Actually testing for a feature is usually a good idea.

Comment: navigator.cookieEnabled always returns true for IE11 , is there any other way to do the same ?

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using [jQuery Cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to manage and create cookies here is a simple way to check for cookies and, after checking for the cookie, run a function based on cookies being enabled or disabled.

```
//Create Session Cookie
$.cookie('test-for-cookie', '1');

//Test for Session Cookie
var yesCookie = $.cookie('test-for-cookie');
if  (yesCookie == 1) { 
    //Run function if cookies are enabled.
} else{
    //If cookies are not enabled run this function.
}
```

[jsFiddle of working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/82CKg/1/)