# How to test whether a browser accepts cookies with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-chrome

I want to test with JavaScript whether the browser supports cookies or not. The following [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703761/) works with Internet Explorer 8 and Firefox 3.6 but not with Google Chrome 5.

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
  document.cookie = "__verify=1";
  var supportsCookies = document.cookie.length > 1 &&
                        document.cookie.indexOf("__verify=1") > -1;
  var thePast = new Date(1976, 8, 16);
  document.cookie = "__verify=1;expires=" + thePast.toUTCString();
  return supportsCookies;
}

if(!areCookiesEnabled()) 
    document.write("<p>Activate cookies!</p>");
else
    document.write("<p>cookies ok</p>");
```

Chrome displays the message "Activate cookies!" regardless of my cookie settings. But if I disallow cookies, Chrome tells me that a cookie could not be set.

Any idea how to test cookie availability with JavaScript in Chrome?

Comment: It works fine for me in Chrome 5 (running on Windows 7).

Comment: I run Chrome 5 on Windows 7 too, but it doesn't work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reliable way to tell if cookies are enabled is to set one, and check for its existence **on the next request**.  Server-side code required.

Comment: I wonder about the fragile cookie handling of Chrome and therefore implemented a cookie test on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the code doesn't work, but you really can simplify your code which will help pin down the problem:

```
function areCookiesEnabled() {
  document.cookie = "__verify=1;expires=" + new Date(1976, 8, 16).toUTCString();
  return  (document.cookie.length > 1);
}

if(!areCookiesEnabled()) 
    document.write("<p>Activate cookies!</p>");
else
    document.write("<p>cookies ok</p>");
```

Also, here is an [excellent overview of Javascript cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html), it might help you pin it down.

Comment: That doesn't work, since (at least) Firefox doesn't accept expired cookies. By the way: why `document.cookie.length > 1` and not `>=`?

Comment: Why are you setting the expiry date to the past?  (Didn't notice that originally).  It doesn't matter what test length you specify because you are testing if it equals '__verify=1' which is a lot more characters than 1 ;)

Comment: I thought `document.cookie.length` were the number of the available cookies. Setting to the past is to remove the cookie after the test.