# How to check if a user accepts cookies

Tags: javascript, yui, yahoo

Using java script,how to check if a user accepts cookies for a domain.
Does YUI has any such component to check ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if the client accepts cookie in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703761/check-if-the-client-accepts-cookie-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

**Library:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function createCookie(name, value, days) {
        var expires;
        if (days) {
            var date = new Date();
            date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
        }
        else expires = "";
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
    }

    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
        }
        return null;
    }

    function eraseCookie(name) {
        createCookie(name, "", -1);
    }

    function areCookiesEnabled() {
        var r = false;
        createCookie("testing", "Hello", 1);
        if (readCookie("testing") != null) {
            r = true;
            eraseCookie("testing");
        }
        return r;
    }
</script>
```

**Code to run:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert(areCookiesEnabled());
</script>
```

**Remember:**

This only works if Javascript are allowed to run!

**Credit:**

This is the re-post from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531393/how-to-detect-if-cookies-are-disabled-is-it-possible). Original author is [balexandre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/28004/balexandre).

Comment: Not bad, but I'd set the cookie to be a session cookie rather than let it expire in one day. E.g. if I deactivate my cookies after visiting the site and than revisit it it won't work. :P

Comment: Yes, sounds reasonable. But this is just for a reference. You can change it to whatever you think is suitable for you.