# How to show error message if cookies are not enabled?

Tags: javascript, html

How to show error message if cookies are not enabled using javascript? I know how to make it using PHP but i want to use javascript intead. I've tried search the answer but it didn't worked out.

Comment: Complete duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167310/how-to-show-a-message-only-if-cookies-are-disabled-in-browser | OR | https://stackoverflow.com/questions/703761/check-if-the-client-accepts-cookie-in-javascript

Comment: but still, no answer yet.

Comment: ?? In all 3 threads you got answers. Aswell you could easily google your header and you have 1000 solutions for your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write functions like this,

```
function checkCookie(){
    var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false   
    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){ 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled)?true:showCookieFail();
}

function showCookieFail(){
  alert('Please enable cookie');
}
```

Comment: i've tried to do this : 

function checkCookie(){
    var cookieEnabled=(navigator.cookieEnabled)? true : false   
    if (typeof navigator.cookieEnabled=="undefined" && !cookieEnabled){ 
        document.cookie="testcookie";
        cookieEnabled=(document.cookie.indexOf("testcookie")!=-1)? true : false;
    }
    return (cookieEnabled)?true:showCookieFail();
}

function showCookieFail(){
  alert('test')
}

but it didn't worked out(no alert)

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan Did you call the ``checkCookie`` function onload?

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan You have to call the function, then only it will work out.

Comment: i did, but still the same

Comment: ``window.onload = function() {
  checkCookie();
};``